# Cache image files in base64 with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, base64

I am trying to write a cache for image files I am working with. I will use this image files to extract parts of the image using canvas.
But it seems not to work right. If i call the function the first time for an url (empty cache) `getBase64OfSubImage` returns the wrong sub-image (empty png). But it seems that it just happens sometimes.
When I run the same command the second time, it returns the correct sub-image.

```
var backgroundImageURLs = Object();

function checkBase64OfImage(url){
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    if(backgroundImageURLs[url] !== undefined){
        dfd.resolve();
    }
    else {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
        req.open('GET', url, true);
        req.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        req.onload = function() {
            buffer = req.mozResponseArrayBuffer || req.response;
            type = req.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');

            var blob = new Blob([buffer], {type: type});
            var fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload = function() {
                backgroundImageURLs[url] = window.btoa(fr.result);
                dfd.resolve();
            };
            fr.readAsBinaryString(blob);
        };
        req.send(null);
    }

    return dfd.promise();
}

function getBase64OfSubImage(url, pos, size){
    if(backgroundImageURLs[url] !== undefined){
        var base64_img = "data:image/png;base64,"+backgroundImageURLs[url];
        var tmp_img = new Image();
        tmp_img.setAttribute("src", base64_img);

        var canvas = $('<canvas/>')[0];
        canvas.width = size[0];
        canvas.height = size[1];

        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(tmp_img, pos[0], pos[1], size[0], size[1], 0, 0, size[0], size[1]);
        return canvas.toDataURL().split(",")[1]; //Get Base64-representation of partial image
    }
    return false;
}
```

Any idea why it is not working as aspected? I use jQuery Deferred/When to make sure the image is fully loaded into my cache:

```
$.when(checkBase64OfImage(background_url)).then(function(){
    img_b64 = getBase64OfSubImage(background_url, background_position, size);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution by myself. The image wasn't fully loaded when trying to process it (in `getBase64OfSubImage`), although it was a Base64-String.

This solution works great:

```
function getBase64OfSubImage(){
    if(backgroundImageURLs[url] !== undefined){
        var base64_img = "data:image/png;base64,"+backgroundImageURLs[url];
        var tmp_img = new Image();
        tmp_img.onload = function(){
            var canvas = $('<canvas/>')[0];
            canvas.width = size[0];
            canvas.height = size[1];

            canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, pos[0], pos[1], size[0], size[1], 0, 0, size[0], size[1]);
            finish(canvas.toDataURL().split(",")[1]); //Get Base64-representation of partial image
        };
        tmp_img.setAttribute("src", base64_img);
    }
    else {
        checkBase64OfImage();
    }
};
```